# Is it possible to copy a String[][] array and a double[][] array into one array? Without using arrayLists or classes

Tags: arrays

I am trying to copy a String[][] array and a double[][] array into one array so that I can make a loop to print out certain columns of the original two arrays next to each other.

Comment: Add the appropriate language tag, such as `java`. Also the question is unclear - ie. how does "String/double[][]" relate to "one array" and "original two arrays"? And what are "certain columns"? And if there are certain columns, why worry about copying [other columns] into "one array"? A little bit of pseudo code (and/or an attempt) including in the question might go long way to increasing question clarity..

Comment: My apologies. I want to do this so that I can print the names of employees from one array and their salaries from another array into a vertical list. For example "Mike Jones $100,000"